Google extension: How to sendMessage when there’s a new active tab?
I use contentscript to query a webpage via the DOM to grab some text. I then send this text to popup.js as the text will be used as title for a newly created tab group.
I find my current approach to not be ideal as sometimes an undefined value is returned.
My goal is for the content script to fire whenever there's a new active tab (new url) and page refresh. I want to grab the text immediately and store it for my popup to use
Contentscript.js – Here I need to query the DOM for some text which is important for the extension. I then need to send the text to the background asap
let workspaceName;
const target = '.db';

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    if (document.querySelector(target)) {
        let name = getWorkspaceDetails();
        observer.disconnect();

        // heres where I send the message
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, name);
    }
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

function getWorkspaceDetails() {
    workspaceName = document.querySelector(target);
    console.log(workspaceName.textContent);
    return workspaceName.textContent;
}

// Initial check in case the element is already present
if (document.querySelector(target)) {
    getWorkspaceDetails();
    observer.disconnect();
}

background.js and popUp.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    workspaceName = msg;
    console.log(`Workpspace: ${msg}`);
});

This only runs on page page refresh and when extension is open. Perhaps this is nature of background script.

Please elaborate what you mean by "tab changes".

I want to sendMessage when ever there’s a new “active tab” that matches URL from manifest.json.
Perhaps I’m going about it the wrong way. But there’s data from certain pages that my extension needs access to quickly.

Use chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated and onHashFragmentUpdated in the background script and/or in the popup script.
